# Memory region flags in Linux: why both VM_WRITE and VM_MAYWRITE are needed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, virtual-memory

"Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager" (2007) by Mel Gorman (here's a [link to the book chapter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html#toc31)) describes the flags of a memory region (vm_area_struct):

> VM_WRITE - Pages may be written
>
> VM_MAYWRITE   - Allow the VM_WRITE flag to be set

I don't understand why Linux needs these two flags, rather than just one of them. From the description above, it sounds like VM_MAYWRITE be set while VM_WRITE is not. In what situations? And how does the Linux kernel behave differently in these situations?

For example, the COW mechanism detects COW-protected pages according to their VM_MAYWRITE flag (see the [source code](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/mm/memory.c#L303)). Doesn't the Linux kernel set the VM_WRITE flag when the VM_MAYWRITE is set? If yes, why not having a single flag and have it set from the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

Memory protection levels can be changed and the kernel uses the `VM_MAY%` flags to determine if such changes are allowable.

> From the description above, it sounds like VM_MAYWRITE be set while VM_WRITE is not. In what situations?

In the situation that memory is initially read-only and you want to make it writable.

> For example, the COW mechanism detects COW-protected pages according to their VM_MAYWRITE flag (see the source code). Doesn't the Linux kernel set the VM_WRITE flag when the VM_MAYWRITE is set? If yes, why not having a single flag and have it set from the beginning?

No, it doesn't. `is_cow_mapping()` isn't checking that the memory is writable, it's checking that the memory can be made writable via `mprotect()`. If it can't, then it's clearly not a COW mapping!